# Python regex to extract number of processors

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a string which contains the number of processors:

SQLDB_GP_Gen**5**_2

The number is after _Gen and before _ (the number 5). How can I extract this using python and regular expressions?

I am trying to do it like this but don't get a match:

```
re.match('_Gen(.*?)_', 'SQLDB_GP_Gen5_2')
```

I was also trying this using pandas:

```
x['SLO'].extract(pat = '(?<=_Gen).*?(?:(?!_).)')
```

But this also wasn't working. (x is a Series)

Can someone please also point me to a book/tutorial site where I can learn regex and how to use with Pandas.

Thanks,

Mick

Comment: You can use lookaround [`(?<=_Gen)[^_]+(?=_)`](https://regex101.com/r/BlrhaB/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.match` searches from the beginning of the string. Use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) instead, and retrieve the first capturing group:

```
>>> re.search(r'_Gen(\d+)_', 'SQLDB_GP_Gen5_2').group(1)
'5'
```

Comment: You could make the search better by only looking for numbers instead of `.*?`

Comment: I think I prefer `'_Gen(\d+?)_'` just for being explicit, and making sure we at least get 1 digit

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I initially went with OP's search pattern as it also works

Comment: In Pandas, there is no need to call `re.search` explicitly, there are dedicated vectorized methods for that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a pattern containing a capturing group:

```
x['SLO'].str.extract(r'_Gen(.*?)_', expand=False)
        ^^^^           ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

To only match a number, use `r'_Gen(\d+)_'`.

**NOTES**:

- With `Series.str.extract`, you need to use a capturing group, the method only returns any value if it is captured
- `r'_Gen(.*?)_'` will match `_Gen`, then will capture any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible, and then match `_`. If you use `\d+`, it will only match 1+ digits.

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks. This is the best solution is using Pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Using re :

```
re.findall(r'Gen(.*)_',text)[0]
```